# Document mode 5 turned on after closing ie developer tool

Tags: html

In my project I use the `<!doctype HTML>` and HTML tag. I support for all the latest browsers including the old browsers starting from ie7

In the HTML page, I use meta tag pointing to the edge document mode, so that the document mode points to the edge mode in the older browser mainly IE 9.

Recently after I pushed code to dev and qa, I saw that enterprise mode was enabled automatically as group access policy.

This enterprise mode basically emulates the older ie8 mode in ie9 browser, IE 10, IE 11 etc., so whatever the document mode I set in page as to use edge mode is not working now and it always set ie8 document mode only.

There is no big issue because of rendering IE 8, but when we open the IE web developer toolbars and after closing the toolbar, the document mode is resetting to document 5, it is showing `ie5 document mode is default mode`. Now the entire UI is distorted.  After I refresh again the document mode set to ie8 mode.

Even though the end user does not know about the web toolbar, this is an issue.

Does any one faced this issue. Please share a work around if any

Comment: Have you tried `<!DOCTYPE html>`? Maybe you are forcing IE mode with metadata headers?

Comment: Justin I'm using doctype HTML only. I had mentioned  it in my description first line. Please check it.

Comment: I mean check uppercase/lowercase letters. It may be the cause.